# 'Bitmap' exists in both 'System.Drawing.Common' and 'System.Drawing'

Tags: c#, emgucv

I've converted project from Emgu 4.1 to Emgu 4.8 and receive next error about Bitmap and Image

"The type 'Bitmap' exists in both 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' and 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'"

What am I missing?

Comment: It sounds like you have referenced, either directly or indirectly, two assemblies that both declare the same types. Examine your dependencies and make sure only those that are required are retained. You have the names of the offending assemblies so it shouldn't be hard to find them.